# Error: Unable to initialize main class test.HelloLucene - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer

Tags: java, lucene

i am new in Java Development and I just started using Lucene. I am trying to get started using the example code given bellow with the following imports but i keep getting the error in the title. Also tried an older version of Lucene with the same results.
Tried to import core and queryparser JARs from the library with no luck. Any suggestions would be welcomed.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;

public class HelloLucene {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    // 0. Specify the analyzer for tokenizing text.
    //    The same analyzer should be used for indexing and searching
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

    // 1. create the index
    Directory index = new RAMDirectory();

    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);

    IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
    addDoc(w, "Lucene in Action", "193398817");
    addDoc(w, "Lucene for Dummies", "55320055Z");
    addDoc(w, "Managing Gigabytes", "55063554A");
    addDoc(w, "The Art of Computer Science", "9900333X");
    w.close();

    // 2. query
    String querystr = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "action";

    // the "title" arg specifies the default field to use
    // when no field is explicitly specified in the query.
    Query q = new QueryParser("title", analyzer).parse(querystr);

    // 3. search
    int hitsPerPage = 10;
    //int hitsTotal = 100000;
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage);
    searcher.search(q, collector);
    ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
    
    // 4. display results
    System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");
    for(int i=0;i<hits.length;++i) {
      int docId = hits[i].doc;
      Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
      System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + d.get("isbn") + "\t" + d.get("title"));
    }

    // reader can only be closed when there
    // is no need to access the documents any more.
    reader.close();
  }

  private static void addDoc(IndexWriter w, String title, String isbn) throws IOException {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("title", title, Field.Store.YES));

    // use a string field for isbn because we don't want it tokenized
    doc.add(new StringField("isbn", isbn, Field.Store.YES));
    w.addDocument(doc);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your project appears to be missing the Lucene libraries (JAR files) it needs. If you are using Maven you can add them as dependencies. You need [Lucene Core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/8.8.2) and [Lucene QueryParser](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-queryparser/8.8.2). Depending on what version of Lucene your code sample was written for, you may need to change the version - or update your code to account for changes to the API.

Comment: If you are including JARs manually (not recommended) you may also need to include the JARs for `lucene-queries` and `lucene-sandbox`. But if you are using Maven (or Gradle) you should get any extra JARs automatically, based on the notes in my first comment.

Comment: After that, you would need to clarify what you mean by "_Tried to import core and queryparser JARs from the library with no luck._", as that is too vague to allow us to help you without some guesswork.